# Telling my supervisor I'm unhappy

Tags: phd, supervision, communication, quitting

An update to [yesterday's post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/167445/im-unhappy-with-my-phd).

A mixture of events has caused me to lose interest in my PhD project. I started on the back of losing a close family member which really didn't give me a good start.

Over the last few months I've grown less interested in the project and I'm growing increasingly frustrated by the lack of support offered by the faculty and supervision team.

I want to communicate this with my supervisor before I resort to handing in my resignation to it's at least noted that I'm unhappy

How do I break the news to them that I'm unhappy?

Comment: "I'm growing increasingly frustrated by the lack of support offered by the faculty and supervision team." And yet you haven't told your advisor you're unhappy about your current situation? Hm.

Comment: That's why I posted here? I'm planning on telling them

Comment: When you say "unhappy", do you mean you want to tell them you are unhappy with them, or that you are unhappy in general?

Answer (score 2):

Simply state the honest reasons to your supervisor why you are quitting, in a respectable way since you might want to hear his/her point of view also. That will give you complete closure, and it will be satisfying for the future you.
There are three possibilities:

1. If he is not interested in guiding you, he will not even try to understand your situation. It is a win situation for you since you made the right choice.
2. He might have other reasons for not supporting you. Probably he does not want to spoon-feed you. Or maybe he going through something much worse than you. It is easy to judge another person.
3. You are simply not interested in the subject. The opinion of the supervisor might not move you.

After the conversation, think about it for one day or two. And, email him about your final decision.

---

Note: There is no need to feel sad about it. You should be happy that you figured it out early. I wish more people could be like you.